# Updating a LIstView

Tags: android-layout

I am creating some code which is supposed to read data from a csv file(username, userprofile image, text). This data is then used to inflate a custom view, then needs to be added to a list view. There should then be a delay before adding the next view.

This is effectively a chat playback feature i am doing for work, so it is basically like a normal messaging app but the messages have been pre-written and need to be played back kind of like a video one message at a time.

i am having trouble with updating the listview. I set the adapter and all the messages are displayed at once instead of one by one with a delay. Hopefully someone can understand what i have tried to explain.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an empty adapter and after [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T)) items one by one. To set the timeout between adding you can use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the array for adapter at once. instead add element one by one and call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter.